# medium-soft flattery that can be said to women without coming out too strong :))

Tags: greetings

Today I have a somewhat funny but serious question:

What medium soft flattery can you say to women without it being interpreted as "sexual harassment" or coming out too strong.

e.g. can you say *sweety* or is it too intimate?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't call a woman handsome...

Comment: @MicahWindsor okay , sorry  :)) corrected the question

Comment: You should ask "without being called out for sexual harassment". "turn on" may not be the right words there.

Comment: @AIQ thank you for your answer, but I am shocked, I think this is not normal, there should be minimum 5 steps between "turn on" and "sexual harassment"

Comment: Your "without being interpreted as a turn on" part is not clear. Who is being turned on? You? The woman? It is not clear what you are saying. I presume you are asking for ways (or words) to flirt without coming out too strong. If you flirt or say "hey sweety" to a woman, why would that turn her on? Why would that turn you on? Are you saying "without the woman thinking that you are turned on or that you are flirting"?

Comment: @AIQ OK, I understand, "turn on" I used in a wrong way. I wanted to ask for ways (or words) to flirt without coming out too strong.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question that can really be answered properly here. What is acceptable or not depends on so many factors, including your personality, tone of voice, the recipient's personality, level of familiarity and past interactions, age, relative age difference, setting/environment, culture and region. My advice to a non-native speaker is not to try to be fancy: play it safe. Say exactly and only what you mean.

Comment: @TypeIA Sir, thank you very much for your sincere advice. I consider it a friendly advice and I really appreciate it. It's time to make America great again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could notice she's had her hair done.
Or maybe comment on her new shoes.
Better make these 'throw away' comments in passing in case it comes off weird.

Try to remember a person's name and use it.

Smile.  I wouldn't say sweety but's just me.

Be happy and look interested.  Difficult if you are unhappy and bored stressed out of your head.